# $(X+4)=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1 \pmod{5}$ by ramification of prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In Milne's algebraic number theory [notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf), on page 65, there is the following example:

> $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1\equiv(X+4)^4\pmod{5}$.

And Milne asks: Why is that obvious?
This comes after discussion of ramification of prime ideals in number fields.

My attempt so far:

> Let $\omega_5=e^{2\pi i/5}$. The field extension $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\omega_5)=K$ is Galois and of degree $4$. The minimal polynomial of $\omega_5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $f(X)=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$.
>   Consider prime ideal $(5)\lhd\mathbb{Z}$ and its factorization in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I don't know the heavy machinery you use, but the problem itself is quite obvious if you see that $(X+4)^4=(X-1)^4(\text{mod }5)$.

Comment: Yes. That's definitely obvious. I'm still wondering what Milne meant, but maybe it's just too ill defined.

Comment: I would think that the factorization $(5)=(\omega_5-1)^4$ comes to the fore - possibly together with the modulo 5 congruence $(x-1)^5\equiv x^5-1$. But it is past my bedtime, so I cannot think straight.